# How does APPEND_NO_FLUSH in FileWritingMessageHandler work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

[The default flush interval is 30000](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/FileWritingMessageHandler.java#L110). Why does the start method of the FileWritingMessageHandler [divide this interval by 3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/FileWritingMessageHandler.java#L366) before scheduling it?

I tried testing the flush with the [spring-cloud-dataflow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) project by creating the following stream: 'time | file --mode=APPEND_NO_FLUSH --directory=test'

Expected result: see 30 messages written in the file after 30 seconds.

Actual result: 0 messages get written in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to schedule the flusher to run more often than the interval, otherwise the flush might take 2x the interval (let's say you write a record at 00:00:01) if we check at 00:00:30, the file won't be flushed until 00:01:00).

By running the flusher at interval / 3, the actual interval will be somewhere between 3 and 4 runs.

With a 30 second interval, the actual interval will be somewhere between 30 and 40 seconds and, on average, 35 seconds.

To get it more accurate we would have to run the flusher much more often.

We should clarify the algorithm in the java docs.

**EDIT**

> 08:44:01.578 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'input', message: GenericMessage [payload=this is another test, headers={timestamp=1484919841573, id=ac106489-73ad-da18-791d-3d0ec515c567, dir=expression}]
>
> 08:44:41.509 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG o.s.i.file.FileWritingMessageHandler - Flushed: /var/folders/rl/6ys7s69j2tqcjyvy8thdsd7m0000gp/T/dataflow-tests/expression/this.out

Comment: This is already explained in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-flushing) `flushInterval - if a file is not written to for this period of time, it is automatically flushed. This is approximate and may be up to 1.33x this time.`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So, if I want it to flush messages to the file every 30-40 seconds in the following stream: 'time | file --mode=APPEND_NO_FLUSH --directory=test' do I need to write a custom FlushPredicate?

Comment: No; you don't need a predicate; turn on DEBUG logging and you'll see the flush - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I created a stream on local-cloud-dataflow-server as follows: "time | file --mode=APPEND_NO_FLUSH --directory=test --logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG" using the applications found here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/ and I don't see any flush messages. The file is completely empty after undeploying too. If I use the default (APPEND) mode, I can see the records in the file.

Comment: Hmmm - I tested the app directly (using one of its test cases, but changing the mode). https://github.com/garyrussell/file/commit/6364cc646d8e9c854e2aa22ce8ab7447798bcdf7 - note that the flush only occurs if the interval expires with no writes - if you write the file, say, ever 5 seconds, the file will only be flushed when the buffer fills up (8192 bytes by default, but I see the sink does not allow configuration of that property). I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4212) to flush on the interval, regardless of intermediate writes.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it gets flushed if I stop the time module, thought it was behaving weird. That was why I was thinking about the FlushPredicate where I would track the timers myself instead of depending on the lastWrite that Flusher uses. It seemed like that was supposed to be configurable. Thanks for your time, explanation and the JIRA issue.

Comment: The flush predicate is used with trigger-based flushes - you can send a message to the trigger method; the predicate is used to match filenames that should be flushed. It's not involved with interval-based flushing.